# JqGrid -Don't change data in Grid after editing if use datatype: "local"

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I use datatype: "local", JqGrid is latest - 4.2
Data don't change in Grid  if I add or edit data. Using by Fiddler I see, that all information is sent to editurl.

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var mydata = [
{id:"1",name:"test",note:"note"},
{id:"2",name:"test2",note:"note2"},
{id:"3",name:"test3",note:"note3"}
];
jQuery("#list4").jqGrid({
data:mydata,
datatype: "local",
colNames:['ID','Client', 'Notes'],
colModel:[ 
    {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int",editable:true,editoptions:{size:10}},
    {name:'name',index:'name', width:100,editable:true,editoptions:{size:10}},
    {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, editable:true,editoptions:{size:20}} ],
editurl:"someurl.php",
pager: '#pcrud',
viewrecords: true,
gridview: true,
width:300
})
jQuery("#list4").jqGrid('navGrid','#pcrud',{});
});
```

HTML:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>My First PHP jqGrid </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/ui.jqgrid.css" />
  <script src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="list4"></table>
  <div id="pcrud"></div>
  <script src="mygrid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is covered a few other times on SO.... you need to use the magic string 'clientArray' as the value of the editurl config option.